# CMFCToolbar only shows ONE button

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, mfc

Even though the resource has five buttons defined, when I run the application only the first is visible.  What gives with MFC?

Comment: Could you show resource definitions related to these five buttons?

Comment: How do you load the ressource toolbar icons?  Show us the code.

Comment: Sorry, the error was in VS.  Once I closed Visual Studio and reopened it I lost all the buttons I added.  Weird, as I was saving and coding regularly.  But once I was down to the one toolbar button, adding more was easy and successful.  I don't know WHAT happened, but it works now!